# Need to bypass cloud flare security

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, beautifulsoup, cloudflare

From past few days i am trying to scrape a website but unable to do so.Due to its cloudflare security "Checking your Browser".

I have tried it in python using selenium, Requests  but unable to achieve main content of website.

Is there any way/method so that we can scrape website who are using cloudflare security?

Do let me know.Thanks
here is the [link](https://www.dustin.se/group/hardvara/datorer-surfplattor/barbara-datorer/professionella?page=1) which i am trying to scrape

Comment: In your selenium script, wait the script for about 20s till the cloudflare warning goes out and content appears.

Comment: HI @Pavindu, Thankyou for suggesting a way i have tried but i was unable to achieve the content page which is required to scrape ,here is it [link](https://www.dustin.se/group/hardvara/datorer-surfplattor/barbara-datorer/professionella?page=1)Can you check at your end ,let me know ?

Comment: Can you please **put the code you have tried?** when I go to that site in my browser, I don't get a cloudflare page.

Comment: Also, do you send user-agent headers when scraping the website content? If no user-agent header is present in your request, such security checks may be activated. You can use a python package to automatically generate user-agent headers for your request.

Comment: But when we are using Selenium wire or Selenium ,We dont send any user agent, right ? ,While using requests we send it ! Yes i do send user agent and all the parameters which are required when using requests module.

Comment: You can use below this [link](https://www.github.com/mandarraut2010/Webscraping_Dustin.se/tree/main/dustin.se_scraper.py) to access my code.i have written it in Selenium first but later changed  to the answer provided by the user below and one more when you go through a normal browser that moment it doesn't appear ,but when you do it through script the response from the page is of cloudflare security ,You can check and let me know or else if its working at your end you can share it on github as well with me

Answer (score 0):

I see, if you try:

```
requests.get('https://www.example.com')
```

You get:

```
Please enable cookies.
```

So you can use the cloudflare-scrape module (python -m pip install cfscrape)

```
import cfscrape
scraper  =  cfscrape.create_scraper()
scraper.get('example.com')
```

Comment: Thankyou I tried doing what you said by i was unable to bypass here is the [link](https://www.dustin.se/group/hardvara/datorer-surfplattor/barbara-datorer/professionella?page=1) can you try at your end let me know if you are getting the exact response html page ,Thanks